# CLIPS who is son or daughter, father or mother, grandfather or grandmother

Tags: clips

I have a quite simple program but never use **CLIPS**.
My task is to show who is who and for whom.
I tried to remake code from my classes but it doesn't work:

```
(defrule MAIN::son
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (m ?y)
    =>
    (assert(son ?y ?x))
    (printout t ?y " is son to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::daughter
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (f ?y)
    =>
    (assert(daughter ?y ?x))
    (printout t ?y " is daughter to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::grandfather
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (father ?z ?x)
    (m ?z)
    =>
    (assert(grandfather ?z ?y))
    (printout t ?z " is grandfather to " ?y crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::grandmother
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (mother ?z ?x)
    (f ?z)
    =>
    (assert(grandmother ?z ?y))
    (printout t ?z " is grandmother to " ?y crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::grandson
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (or (father ?y ?z)
        (mother ?y ?z)
    )
    (m ?z)
    =>
    (assert(grandson ?z ?x))
    (printout t ?z " is grandson to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::granddaughter
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (or (father ?y ?z)
        (mother ?y ?z)
    )
    (f ?z)
    =>
    (assert(grandson ?z ?x))
    (printout t ?z " is granddaughter to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::brother
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (or (father ?x ?z)
        (mother ?x ?z)
    )
    (notancestor ?y ?z)
    (m ?z)
    =>
    (assert(brother ?z ?y))
    (printout t ?z " is brother "to  ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::sister
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (or (father ?x ?z)
        (mother ?x ?z)
    )
    (notancestor ?y ?z)
    (f ?z)
    =>
    (assert(sister ?z ?y))
    (printout t ?z " is sister to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::near_ancestor
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
        )
        (or     (father ?x ?z)
            (mother ?x ?z)
        )
        =>
        (assert(near_ancestor ?z ?y))
        (printout ?z " is near_ancestor to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::ancestor
        (ancestor ?x ?y)
        (near_ancestor ?y ?z)
        =>
        (assert(ancestor ?x ?z))
        (printout t ?z " is ancestor to " ?x crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::near_descendant
    (or (father ?x ?y)
        (mother ?x ?y)
    )
    (or (father ?x ?z)
        (mother ?x ?z)
    )
    =>
    (assert(near_descendant ?y ?z))
    (printout t ?x " is near_descendant to" ?z crlf)
)

(defrule MAIN::descendant
    (descendant ?x ?y)
    (near_descendant ?y ?z)
    =>
    (assert(descendant ?z ?x))
    (printout t ?x " is descendant to " ?z crlf)
)
```

I'm not sure about entries data:

```
(deffacts startup
    (father Adam Kain)
    (father Adam Abel)
    (father Adam Set)
    (mother Ewa Kain)
    (mother Ewa Abel)
    (mother Ewa Set)
)
```

I have such error in **CLIPS**

> CLIPS> (run)
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Kain
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Kain
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Ewa is near_descendant to Kain
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Kain
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Set was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Set
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Kain
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Abel was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Abel
>   [ROUTER1] Logical name Kain was not recognized by any routers
>   Adam is near_descendant to Kain

And I've stuck on it.
I will be appreciated for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your code

```
(printout ?z " is near_ancestor to " ?x crlf)
```

should be this

```
(printout t ?z " is near_ancestor to " ?x crlf)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. For the near_ancestor - done. Maybe you know why it doesn't work for the son/daughter and sister/brother? An as for the grandfather and grandmother should I add some like that: (grandmother Name Kain)  (grandmother Name Abel)  (grandmother Name Set)?

Comment: Your test facts need to include the facts indicating whether a person is male or female. There are lots of other errors in your code. For example, (notancestor ?y ?z) should be (not (ancestor ?y ?z)). Also the near_descendant rule prints that ?x is a near descendent to ?z when it should print ?y is a near descendent to ?z. To debug your rules, start with just one and when you verify that rule works, add another and verify that one.